# Designing a circuit of gates in Clojure and doing forward and backpropagation

Tags: clojure, machine-learning

I am reading [Hacker's guide to Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/neuralnets/). Since I am also learning Clojure, I tried to implement them in Clojure.

I would like the feedback about what could be more idiomatic and better in the below code. Also I have some problems which i have asked at the end.

Here I have simple gates like `Multiply` that take inputs from other gates and produce output. The circuit is made with the composition of these gates.

Two functions `forward` and `backward` are defined. `forward` computes the output value of the circuit when we start from some input value. `backward` computes the gradient or the pull that should be applied on the inputs to make the output value more positive.

`backward` uses `forward` for its calculation. Using `backward` we get some values (pulls) which after applying on the input would produce output value greater than before.

```
;; A single unit has forward value and backward gradient.
(defrecord Unit 
    [value gradient name]
  Object
  (toString [_]
    (str name " : ")))

;; A Gate has two units of inputs. 
(defrecord Gate
    [^:Unit input-a ^:Unit input-b])

(defprotocol GateOps
  "Basic Gate Operations: Forward and Backward are two 
  protocol-operations need to be supported by  each gate."
  (forward [this] "Give the output-value from its input - used in 
going forward the circuit. ")
  (backward [this back-grad] "Gives the gradient to its input -
argument has back-grad which is gradient from its output. Backward calcuates the
derivative for generating the backward pull."))

;; Unit is basic unit of cirtuit and hence simple operations.
(extend-protocol GateOps
  Unit
  (forward [this]
    (:value this))
  (backward [this back-grad]
    {this back-grad}))

;; MultiplyGate gets two inputs and * their values going forward.
(defrecord MultiplyGate [input-a input-b]
  GateOps
  (forward [this]
    (* (forward (:input-a this)) (forward (:input-b this))))

  (backward [this back-grad]
    (let [input-a (:input-a this)
          input-b (:input-b this)
          val-a (forward input-a)
          val-b (forward input-b)]
      (merge-with + (backward input-a (* val-b back-grad))
                  (backward input-b (* val-a back-grad))))))

;; AddGate add values of two  inputs.
(defrecord AddGate [input-a input-b]
  GateOps
  (forward [this]
    (+ (forward (:input-a this)) (forward (:input-b this))))

  (backward [this back-grad]
    (let [input-a (:input-a this)
          input-b (:input-b this)]
      (merge-with + (backward input-a (* 1.0 back-grad))
                  (backward input-b (* 1.0 back-grad))))))


(defn sig 
  "Sigmoid function : f(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-x))"
  [x]
  (/ 1 (+ 1 (Math/pow Math/E (- x)))))

;; SigmoidGate applies sig on input.
(defrecord SigmoidGate [gate]
  GateOps
  (forward [this]
    (sig (forward (:gate this))))

  (backward [this back-grad]
    (let [s (forward this) 
          ;; s is (sig input) i.e. output
          ds (* s (- 1 s) back-grad)]
      (backward (:gate this) ds))))


(defmacro defunit 
  "Creates a Unit that also stores the name of the variable."
  [var-name body]
  `(def ~var-name (~@body (name '~var-name))))

;; neural network : f(x,y) = sig(a*x + b*y + c)
(defunit a (->Unit 1.0 0.0))
(defunit b (->Unit 2.0 0.0))
(defunit c (->Unit -3.0 0.0))
(defunit x (->Unit -1.0 0.0))
(defunit y (->Unit 3.0 0.0))

(def ax (->MultiplyGate a x))
(def by (->MultiplyGate b y))
(def axc (->AddGate ax c))
(def axcby (->AddGate axc by))
(def sigaxcby (->SigmoidGate axcby ))
```

Running:

```
neurals.core> (forward sigaxcby)
0.8807970779778823      
neurals.core> (clojure.pprint/pprint (backward sigaxcby 1.0))
{{:value 2.0, :gradient 0.0, :name "b"} 0.31498075621051985,    
 {:value 3.0, :gradient 0.0, :name "y"} 0.20998717080701323,    
 {:value -3.0, :gradient 0.0, :name "c"} 0.10499358540350662,    
 {:value -1.0, :gradient 0.0, :name "x"} 0.10499358540350662,
 {:value 1.0, :gradient 0.0, :name "a"} -0.10499358540350662}

nil
```

Queries:

1. `Backward` is inefficient. It calculates the `forward` on same sub-circuit multiple times.
2. Once I know the gradients, how do I apply them to the circuit's input values because they are immutable?

I think these problems show that there is a design flaw.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it finally drew to me, it was a `Ahaa!!!` moment.

I think that the solution to both my problems lies in removing state - which is the essence of Functional Programming..

Rather than storing `value` and `gradient` in my `Units`, i just let them be the `left-most-end-points` of the circuit. The circuit as a whole now is just a function. The circuit is supplied with initial input-values. When `Unit` is asked about its `forward`, it returns the value provided in the `input-data` flowing around the circuit.

```
;; A single unit is the input-to-the-circuit.
;; It is identified by its `id`.
(defrecord Unit 
    [id name]
  Object
  (toString [_]
    (str name " : ")))

;; A Gate has two units of inputs. 
(defrecord Gate
    [^:Unit input-a ^:Unit input-b])

(defprotocol GateOps
  "Basic Gate Operations: Forward and Backward are two 
  protocol-operations need to be supported by  each gate."
  (forward [this _] "Give the output-value from input gate(s) used in 
going forward the circuit. ")
  (backward [this back-grad init-values] "Gives the gradient to its 
input - argument(s) are back-grad : which is gradient from its output. 
init-values : stores the input of units given to the circuit. It is 
propagated around the circuit. Backward calcuates the derivative for 
generating the backward pull."))

;; Unit is mouth of cirtuit and hence simple operations.
(extend-protocol GateOps
  Unit
  (forward [this input-values]
    (let [id (:id this)]
      {id (input-values id)}))
  (backward [this back-grad init-values]
    {(:id this) back-grad}))

;; MultiplyGate gets two inputs and * their values going forward.
(defrecord MultiplyGate [id input-a input-b]
  GateOps
  (forward [this input-values]
      (let [id (:id this)
        input-a (:input-a this)
        input-b (:input-b this)
        val-a-map (forward input-a input-values)
        val-b-map (forward input-b input-values)]
    (-> 
     (merge-with + val-a-map val-b-map)
     (assoc   id (* (val-a-map (:id input-a)) 
                    (val-b-map (:id input-b)))))))

  (backward [this back-grad init-values]
    (let [input-a (:input-a this)
          input-b (:input-b this)
          val-a (init-values (:id input-a))
          val-b (init-values (:id input-b))]
      (-> 
       (merge-with + (backward input-a (* val-b back-grad) init-values)
                   (backward input-b (* val-a back-grad) init-values))
       (assoc  (:id this) back-grad)))))

;; AddGate add values of two  inputs.
(defrecord AddGate [id input-a input-b]
  GateOps
  (forward [this input-values]
      (let [id (:id this)
        input-a (:input-a this)
        input-b (:input-b this)
        val-a-map (forward input-a input-values)
        val-b-map (forward input-b input-values)]
    (-> 
     (merge-with + val-a-map val-b-map)
     (assoc   id (+ (val-a-map (:id input-a)) 
                    (val-b-map (:id input-b)))))))

  (backward [this back-grad init-values]
    (let [input-a (:input-a this)
          input-b (:input-b this)]
      (-> 
       (merge-with + (backward input-a (* 1.0 back-grad) init-values)
                   (backward input-b (* 1.0 back-grad) init-values))
       (assoc   (:id this) back-grad)))))


(defn sig 
  "Sigmoid function : f(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-x))"
  [x]
  (/ 1 (+ 1 (Math/pow Math/E (- x)))))

;; SigmoidGate applies sig on input.
(defrecord SigmoidGate [id gate]
  GateOps
  (forward [this input-values]
      (let [id (:id this)
        input-a (:gate this)
        val-a-map (forward input-a input-values)]
    (-> 
     val-a-map
     (assoc   id (sig (val-a-map (:id input-a)))))))

  (backward [this back-grad init-values]
    (let [s (init-values (:id this))
          ;; s is (sig input) i.e. output
          ds (* s (- 1 s) back-grad)]
      (->
       (backward (:gate this) ds init-values)
       (assoc (:id this) back-grad)))))


(defmacro defunit 
  "Creates a Unit that also stores the name of the variable."
  [var-name body]
  `(def ~var-name (~@body (name '~var-name))))

;; neural network : f(x,y) = sig(a*x + b*y + c)
(defunit a (->Unit 0))
(defunit b (->Unit 1))
(defunit c (->Unit 2))
(defunit x (->Unit 3))
(defunit y (->Unit 4))

(def ax (->MultiplyGate 5 a x))
(def by (->MultiplyGate 6 b y))
(def axc (->AddGate 7 ax c))
(def axcby (->AddGate 8 axc by))
(def sigaxcby (->SigmoidGate 9 axcby ))

(clojure.pprint/pprint 
 (backward sigaxcby 1.0 
           ;; forward takes a map { unit-id  input-to-unit }
           (forward sigaxcby {0 1.0
                              1 2.0
                              2 -3.0
                              3 -1.0
                              4 3.0
                              })))
```

Terminal View:

```
neurals.core>           (clojure.pprint/pprint (forward sigaxcby {0 1.0
                              1 2.0
                              2 -3.0
                              3 -1.0
                              4 3.0
                              }))
{0 1.0,
 7 -4.0,
 1 2.0,
 4 3.0,
 6 6.0,
 3 -1.0,
 2 -3.0,
 9 0.8807970779778823,
 5 -1.0,
 8 2.0}
nil
neurals.core> (clojure.pprint/pprint 
                  (backward sigaxcby 1.0 
                    ;; forward takes a map { unit-id  input-to-unit }
                     (forward sigaxcby {0 1.0
                              1 2.0
                              2 -3.0
                              3 -1.0
                              4 3.0
                              })))

{0 -0.10499358540350662,
 7 0.10499358540350662,
 1 0.31498075621051985,
 4 0.20998717080701323,
 6 0.10499358540350662,
 3 0.10499358540350662,
 2 0.10499358540350662,
 9 1.0,
 5 0.10499358540350662,
 8 0.10499358540350662} 
nil
```

This looks good to me.. :)